# Is Wally there?

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

*Inpired by recent [Stand-up Maths' video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dET2l8l3upU).*

### Task

Wrapping a list `x` can be seen as inserting "line-breaks" into `x` every `n`-th element, or forming a matrix from `x` with `n` columns (feeding rows first). To be perfectly rigorous in the definition of `x` wrapped into a matrix, we can pad the last row with `0`s.

Given a list `x` of positive digits and a matrix `M` of positive digits, determine whether `x` can be wrapped into any matrix that contains `M` as a submatrix. In other words, is there any `n` such that wrapping `x` into a matrix of `n` columns results in a matrix that contains `M`?

### Rules

- Any reasonable input format is acceptable (list, string, array, etc.).
- As for output, please follow the [defaults for decision-problem challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/decision-problem/info).
- `x` is guaranteed to be longer than number of elements in `M`.
- You don't need to handle empty inputs.
- Some wrappings may result in the final line shorter - that's fine.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your code as short as possible.

### Examples

```
x=1231231
M=23
  31

Possible wrappings:
n>=7
1231231

n=6
123123
1

n=5
12312
31

n=4
1231
231

n=3
123
123
1

n=2
12
31
23
1

n=1
1
2
3
1
2
3
1

Output: True (4th wrapping)
```

```
x=1231231
M=23
  32
Possible wrappings: same as above
Output: False (none of the wrappings contain M as submatrix)
```

### Test cases

**Truthy**

```
x; M
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1]; [[2,3],[3,1]]
[3,4,5,6,7,8]; [[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
[3,4,5,6,7,8]; [[3,4],[7,8]]
[1,2,3]; [[1,2,3]]
[1,2,3]; [[1],[2],[3]]
[1,1,2,2,3,3]; [[1],[2],[3]]
[1,1,3,4,5,6]; [[1],[4],[6]]
```

**Falsey**

```
x; M
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1]; [[2,3],[3,2]]
[1,1,2,2,3,3]; [[1,2,3]]
[1,2,3]; [[4,5,6]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]; [[2,3],[4,5]]
```

Comment: Suggested truthy test case: `[1,1,3,4,5,6]; [[1],[4],[6]]`. (That will not work if the code just checks that the positions of `4` in `[3,4]` and `6` in `[5,6]` are the same as the position of the _first_ `1` in `[1,1]`.)

Comment: Suggested falsey test case: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]; [[2,3],[4,5]]`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - the rows of the wrappings *are* left-aligned.  The case you describe wraps once between ```6``` and ```7```, and the new second row is just ```[7,8]```, underneath ```[3,4]``` (it's not a full row).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Ah, I'm an idiot.. I've been using `ä` instead of `ô` in [the program I had linked in my now deleted comment](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6KGV/480ntt6aF3x4S3ntkZc2Jv@qGHe4T2H9@uF1R7eARRB8IGcwNra2tNzDi/4r/M/OjraUMdIx1gHSsbqREcDGUAKxImN1VGIBrJMdEx1zHTMdSxA0mAukAERwKUESCGkwYaDJCAMdEEgYQSyES4BkgI5B6c01D6YNMg2M2RjsXnHCIfx2JwEMR3ZQLh9EBWgIAACAA).. :/ Ignore what I said. (I've actually been able to find a slightly shorter approach, and have posted my answer. And I've deleted my comment above to reduce potential confusion, since I was just blind.)

Comment: I'm beginning to think Matt Parker needs his own tag here, given the number of challenges inspired by his videos.  (I wonder if he's aware of this?)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>126</s> <s>121</s> 120 bytes

*Edit: -5 bytes thanks to Aaron Hayman*

```r
function(x,m,r=nrow(m)){for(o in l<-seq(x)-1)for(s in l+o)T=T&any(c(x,!x,!x)[outer(1:r,(r+s)*(1:ncol(m)-1),`+`)+o]-m)
T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZFha4MwEIa/@ysyCiM3zw/arRtl/gu/jUGdVSaYSxcjVcZ@u8tFS6mwdYMQcu89ubx3MaOqqU/HqqPC1ppkjwpNSkYfpQL4rLSRWtQkmueoLT9kD1EMLLZeDDVkaXab0yALd/WGF7zozpZGxluD0oQt3LkjFbpxBd1l3IU7CPVrpCDIvsaVqPKmHbZCidrXzMXR5IdDuRd9wN5c4RgTXOO8AxZvNe2d7EIXSNYATuwa7/EBN/iIT2fSi8xO@nWa2UvSv35mpvDnNBdIvLsLiDHu4k/obG6Bem8bRoOVsKaz76fhkbZ@gDT8f4TJVZu/Nzw5XaSX/ufX@C8Axm8)

Outputs `TRUE` if <s>wally isn't there</s> `m` is *not* present in any wrapping of `x`, `FALSE` if it is.

Calculates the indices of positions of <s>wally</s> `m` for each possible `o`ffset (the first position in the wrapped matrix) and `s`pacing (the width of the wrapped matrix), and checks that the elements of `x` at these indices are all equal to `m`.
To avoid lengthly calculations to keep the indices in-range, we first extend `x` with enough zeros to cover the biggest `o` & `s`: this is the ugly-looking `(c(x,!x,!x)`.

Comment: Can shave off 5 by removing if and a couple of refinements [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHdTsMwDIXv@xRBu4mpd9EOBprIbV8CIa10rYiUn5GmWifg2UucdppWCQZSFMXHX5xjxw1aml4MTWcqL63hPWp0wjh74Brgo7GOWyYNU0/Ltn7nPSwzILGNYmqhEMVnqRSvwtUbWvBsO187nm0ccpe2cBuOprIqFAyXcZtuIbUvQmhIiq9hwbzr/NtxwzSTsWrJDq7c7@sd6xNyF0pnmOMKpx2wepVmF@QQhoCTBnBiV3iH97jGB3w8k1EkdtSv08RekvH1MzOGP6epQB7dXUCEURd/QidzMzR6WxOaLFhTqvY0O2N9nJ85/n@C@VWXv/c7Gp2l5/an1@grAIZv "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @AaronHayman Thanks!  Those are both really nice golfs!  I don't think I'd realised that one can assign using ```<-``` within the ```for()``` bit.  Nice.

Comment: @AaronHayman - and removing the ```if``` also lets us save another byte by reversing the output.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
1 e.,@(E."2-@#\]\"{])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBNC4JAEIbv/ooXCzZhXXI1i4VAiDx1io56iFAkgqCPQ/Tjt/3QVBKhw8wyM8/OvLxn6TJSYi1AQDGHUOEzbPa7VAYoGE1mW@ZyP5lkeea@c096TnGqriCH2/NRvYitMANHCCpUCuChhHq4KWxusBARFppDjCVWhrQ9U/c4TY0xVJjtnWvt7wBTFVBd/EFoRlNDXKQi/nKNHqd2Iz1e7q0ZtRcq8xEv@vp/b1Nhbgyob/areWdqFckP)

Bulk of the work done by `E.` builtin, which can search for one 2D matrix within another, and even extends to higher dimensions.

- `-@#\]\"{]` Every possible wrapping.
- `E."2` Does the matrix match at each position? (returns 0/1 matrices)
- `,@` Flatten
- `1 e.` Is 1 an element of that?

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 24 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Generates all possible wrappings and checks if the left argument is a submatrix of one.

```
{1∊∾(⥊⍷⥊˜⟨↑⟩∾1⊸+)¨↕≠}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=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)

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 100 bytes

```
f(a,b)=sum(n=#b,#a,!!matrix(-#a\-n,n-#b+1,x,y,b==matrix(#b~,#b,i,j,if(#a>=k=(x+i-2)*n+y+j-1,a[k]))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZFBTsMwEEXFTdJ6Y5PvRZLSVrLcG7BkZSI0oQpym0ZRmkrJhouw6QZxJjgNdpJCEa0X1v_zRn9G9ttHRbV9eqmOx_dDk8vl5zrnhEzo_WHHS80yMMJksqOmti2XjB5liVKyLIzQokOm9chY9grXbrGBzTmjld5q3oZWxuK2DLtwIyOQ2abCnWHW180DVVXRcQrkKqhqWzZOTr2ZBs9UFDxHQEIgMMZEiJFgvFNXckJ56bVJMMMd5lhg6X1v1WCvcPXD-kyn7qnhoxF_gIlUrJJTs6_6JS6RccxAZmp-NuD_6vGlxKtL9GBIPwO_83ymM2majq97-tFv)

Generates all possible wrappings, and all of their submatrices of the given size, and check if the second argument is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 133 bytes

```
f(L,M,w)=0^{\sum_{m=1}^K\sum_{X=w}^m\sum_{Y=0}^K\prod_{j=0}^{M.\length-1}\{M[j+1]=L[X+Ym+1-w+\mod(j,w)+\floor(j/w)m],0\}}
K=L.length
```

- L: list of positive digits (x in question)
- M: matrix, flattened because Desmos doesn't have 2D arrays
- w: width of M

Outputs 0 for truthy and 1 for falsey.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hztgcyq175)

Comment: You dont need the outer `0^{...}`, because as long as it's truthy or falsy, it's fine

Comment: You can emit the first newline if you put the `K=L.length` before the `f(...)=...`

Comment: @Steffan the language has no convention for truthy/falsy as required by the decision-problem tag default; the only construction that can be used for list filters and the condition in piecewises is the direct result of numeric comparisons: `=`, `>` etc.

Comment: @Steffan Omitting the first newline doesn't work for me. As I understand it, when [scoring Desmos equations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/scoring-desmos-equations), newlines typically denote "file boundaries," which means copy-paste each line separately *excluding* the surrounding newlines. Copying the newline before the `f` is not allowed because the newline would then double as a file boundary character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
ＦＥθ⪪θ⊕κＰ⊙ι⊙κ⊙ι⊙ξ⁼ηＥ✂ιλ⊕π¹✂σν⊕ς
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYyxDsIwDER/xaMjmaEwMjEwMHTqGGWIQlCjmjRN0wq@PiRqGXqSfXd60pleRzNqzvk1RsBWB5wIusAu1fDwJtq39ck@cRBF0C6cXIjOJ7z5LzqCasNme/sQ3KdF84w9QZ3s2BlbKR8ngyBoym18JvBHvoq/rjlL2dCZLrR/RVKWUKwWpfJp5R8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` if it finds Wally, nothing if not. Explanation: Another answer that generates all submatrices of all wrappings.

```
ＦＥθ⪪θ⊕κ
```

Generate all wrappings of the list.

```
Ｐ⊙ι⊙κ⊙ι⊙ξ⁼ηＥ✂ιλ⊕π¹✂σν⊕ς
```

Check whether the matrix exists as a submatrix.

Unfortunately Charcoal only has 11 loop variables so I can't save a further byte like this:

```
⊙Ｅθ⪪θ⊕κ⊙ι⊙κ⊙ι⊙ξ⁼ηＥ✂ιλ⊕π¹✂σν⊕ς
```

Explanation:

```
  θ                             Input list
 Ｅ                              Map over digits
    θ                           Input list
   ⪪                            Wrapped to width
      κ                         Current index
     ⊕                          Incremented
⊙                               Any wrapping satisfies
        ι                       Current wrapping
       ⊙                        Any row satisfies
          λ                     Current row
         ⊙                      Any column satisifies
            ι                   Current wrapping
           ⊙                    Any row satisfies
              ξ                 Inner row
             ⊙                  Any column satisifies
                η               Input matrix
               ⁼                Equals
                   ι            Current wrapping
                  ✂   ¹         Sliced from
                    μ           Outer row index to
                      π         Inner row index
                     ⊕          Incremented
                 Ｅ              Map over rows
                         σ      Current row
                        ✂       Sliced from
                          ν     Outer column index to
                            ς   Inner column index
                           ⊕    Incremented
                                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>27</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.œεεŒIнgù}øεŒIgù€Q]˜à
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@jkc1vPbT06yfPC3vTDO2sP7wBzgMxHTWsCY0/PObzg//9oYx0THVMdMx1zHYtYrmgQN1YnGsSJBQA) or [or verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6H@9o5PPbT239eikiAt70w/vrD28A8wBMs9tjQisra09Pefwgv86/6Ojow11jHSMdaBkrE50NJABpECc2FgdhWggy0THVMdMx1zHAiQN5gIZEAFcSoAUQhpsOEgCwkAXBBJGIBvhEiApkHNwSkPtg0mDbDNDNhabd4xwGI/NSRDTkQ2E2wdRAQoCIAAA) or [try it online with step-by-step debug-lines](https://tio.run/##nZG/SgNBEMZ7n2JIY7Oawr8oIYUQSafYGa5YL5Ps4N7uuTvnBUsfQVsLH8A2ooWNIZUQfAZf5Ly9nAaDhQgLy87HfN9vdqyXZ4RF0eiQ8wxk0ozXNHneg0a71TjB2Jp@XU4kOxoFoSteH9srjUNkkFpDKh0TkzUe7ABY4ZLP@vS2VTV0rAOUsSp1gw6CHjqq0sJEQOxQMoK9RKdlmpIZVrKHnFiBBE9XCHiRSQ1sq8Cc@qVSp/vfqWfj2Xh6031/GU6eoznQKaVNdtKk1uM@@LwOczb3zdjqLDE@dH5cP0yelkb4gg/3v5AV0lDx35gXxAcK43MYfH/kAIhX/U/nZZMSf36O6xm0ZEYTpLe7eenIpiDL/DTzqvJI5IiSLBGQKwo55WozBw59pqudTu5FUfQ2xKbYEttiR@xGK73wjEQvPKJP).

**Explanation:**

```python
.œ           # Get all partitions of the first (implicit) input-list
  ε          # Map over each partition:
   ε         #  Map over each inner list:
    Œ        #   Get all sublists of this list
     I       #   Push the second input-matrix
      н      #   Pop and leave just its first row
       g     #   Pop and push its length to get the width of the matrix
        ù    #   Only leave all sublists of this length, to get all overlapping
             #   parts with a size equal to the width of the input-matrix
   }ø        #  After the inner map: zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
     ε       #  Map over each list of lists:
      Œ      #   Get all sublists of this list
       I     #   Push the second input-matrix again
        g    #   Pop and push its length to get the height of the matrix
         ù   #   Only leave all sublists of this length, to get all matrices
             #   with the same dimensions as the input-matrix
          €  #   Map over each inner matrix:
           Q #    Check if its equal to the second (implicit) input-matrix
  ]          # Close both maps
   ˜         # Flatten
    à        # Get the maximum to check if any were truthy
```